# How can I have a prototype.js Template encode HTML entities?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, html-entities

If I have a [prototype.js Template](http://prototypejs.org/api/template) which generates HTML code from a JavaScript object, how can I have it automatically escape HTML entities in the JavaScript object's data so that the HTML doesn't break?

Sample JavaScript code:

```
var data = {
    name: 'Josh',
    url: 'http://josh.gitlin.name/',
    statement: 'I\'m a JavaScript and PHP developer. Find me on Stack Overflow and say "hi"!'
}

var template = new Template(
    '<div><label>Name: <input name=\"name\" value=\"#{name}\"></label></div>'+
    '<div><label>URL: <input name=\"url\" value=\"#{url}\"></label></div>'+
    '<div><label>Personal Statement: <input name=\"statement\" value=\"#{statement}\"></label></div>'
);

$('test').update(template.evaluate(data));
```

[JSFiddle code for the above](http://jsfiddle.net/HtRmS/)

The above code produces a malformed `<input>` tag because `data.statement` contains a quotation mark `"`. How can I have the `Template` automatically escape HTML entities in the above example without modifying the `data` object nor cloning the `data` object?
​

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, two things need to happen:

1. The `escape` method of the `Template` class must know to escape HTML entities
2. The [`escapeHTML` method which Prototype.js adds to the `String` object](http://prototypejs.org/api/string) must be extended to encode quotation marks into `&quot;` entities. (And possibly more. It's *way* too simplistic right now...)

Both these two can be achieved with the following code:

```
String.prototype.escapeHTML = String.prototype.escapeHTML.wrap(function(proceed){
    return proceed().replace(/"/g,'&quot;');
});

Template.addMethods({
    evaluateEscapeHTML: function(object) {
        if (object && Object.isFunction(object.toTemplateReplacements))
          object = object.toTemplateReplacements();

        return this.template.gsub(this.pattern, function(match) {
          if (object == null) return (match[1] + '');

          var before = match[1] || '';
          if (before == '\\') return match[2];

          var ctx = object, expr = match[3],
              pattern = /^([^.[]+|\[((?:.*?[^\\])?)\])(\.|\[|$)/;

          match = pattern.exec(expr);
          if (match == null) return before;

          while (match != null) {
            var comp = match[1].startsWith('[') ? match[2].replace(/\\\\]/g, ']') : match[1];
            ctx = ctx[comp];
            if (null == ctx || '' == match[3]) break;
            expr = expr.substring('[' == match[3] ? match[1].length : match[0].length);
            match = pattern.exec(expr);
          }

          return before + String.interpret(ctx).escapeHTML();
        });
    }
});
```

**This code will extend Prototype.js and add a new `evaluateEscapeHTML` method to Templates**, so this code should be run *once*, and from then on, any `Template` will now have a new `evaluateEscapeHTML` method:

```
var template = new Template(
    '<div><label>Name: <input name=\"name\" value=\"#{name}\"></label></div>'+
    '<div><label>URL: <input name=\"url\" value=\"#{url}\"></label></div>'+
    '<div><label>Personal Statement: <input name=\"statement\" value=\"#{statement}\"></label></div>'
);

$('test').update(template.evaluate(data));
```

[JSFiddle to test this](http://jsfiddle.net/PabjP/3/)

Note that I had to *duplicate* the *entire* `evaluate` method from the `Template` class from prototype.js version 1.7. This has a major downside in that if future versions of the `evaluate` method are improved, my code needs to be improved also. I couldn't find any better way to do this, however.

The specific modification to the `evaluate` method which I made was to change this line:

```
return before + String.interpret(ctx);
```

to:

```
return before + String.interpret(ctx).escapeHTML();
```

That's all, which is why it's such a shame I couldn't somehow `extend` or `wrap` the rest of the code...

Answer (score 1):

Reading the source code, there is nothing in the Template that would escape html. Furthermore, the provided `String#escapeHTML` is pretty terrible as it attempts to strips tags (wtf) with regex (wtf2) and doesn't even escape quotes.

You could manually escape your strings with this:

```
function escapeHTML(text) {
    var map = {
        "&" : "amp",
        "'": "#39",
        '"': "quot",
        "<": "lt",
        ">": "gt"

    };

    return text.replace( /[&'"<>]/g, function(m) {
        return "&" + map[m] + ";";
    });
}
```

Comment: I just wrote my own code and was amazed at how terrible `escapeHTML` is. Do you have a better suggestion? If not, I like the code you provided. (Also thoughts on my solution welcomed)

Comment: @Josh For escaping html I think this function should do the job well. I am not familiar with prototype enough to inject this into core functionality of Template though. So I can't say anything about that. I would just use a real templating engine, it's not like there is a lack of them. :P

Comment: I am familiar with prototype enough to inject this into core functionality of Template, and I did. `:-)` Thanks for your function, I will use that well.